# Do I need to get a transit visa to explore London during a layover?

Tags: uk, london, transit, visas-on-arrival, indian-citizens

Details: I hold a Indian passport with a valid and unexpired US student visa (F1). I would be travelling from Los Angeles to Mumbai via a 18 hr layover at London Heathrow airport in December 2012.

Comment: What kind of transit visa do you have? ([see the links in this answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10546/do-turkish-citizens-need-a-visa-to-come-to-the-uk-for-one-day/10560#10560))

Comment: @chinmay As one indian citizen to another: you will **not be able** to take in the sights. You'd need a **regular UK visa** to get out of the airport. You just don't need a transit visa to change terminals. You have an unexp. US F1 visa, so you should be able to change planes without needing a transit visa even if you do venture into the non-international portions of the airport.

Answer (score 8):

1) You don't have to apply for a transit visa **if** you are eligible for a Transit Without Visa (TWOV) concession. The rules for TWOV are outlined here: http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/sitecontent/documents/policyandlaw/carriers/ukvisarequirements.pdf

Indian citizens may not TWOV in general. However, it looks like you
    meet the following exception:

> **TWOV is a concession which does not apply to nationals of the
>   countries shown above in red who need visas even when in direct
>   airside transit unless they are in possession of one of the following
>   documents:**
> ...
>    (ab) a valid visa for entry to Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the
>   United States of America and a valid airline ticket for travel via the
>   United Kingdom as part of a journey from the country in respect of
>   which the visa is held to another country or territory;

So you should be able to TWOV.

2) You can do sightseeing.

Comment: >You can do sightseeing.
You mean without a Transit Visa and TWOV concession applied ?

Comment: @scrapcodes: No, you have to get a visa or TWOV, and then you can do sightseeing.